# Я хочу вывести в label текст введенный в пользователем в QTextEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

когда запускаю приложение и нажимаю на кнопку, программа завершается с ошибкой `finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)` в PyCharm, и с ошибкой `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'textEdit'` в Visual Studio Code.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

       MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
       MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
       self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
       self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
       self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
       self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 350, 75, 23))
       self.pushButton.setObjectName("отправить")
       self.pushButton.clicked.connect(Ui_MainWindow.text_btn)
       self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
       self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 260, 104, 71))
       self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
       self.textEdit.setPlainText('Hello World')
       self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
       self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 120, 47, 13))
       self.label.setObjectName("label")
       MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
       self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
       self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 21))
       self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
       MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
       self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
       self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
       MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
       self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
       QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
       _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
       MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("test", "test"))
       self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
       self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
    def text_btn(self):
       print('rabotaem')
       text1 = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
       self.label.setText(text1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
   ui = Ui_MainWindow()
   ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
   MainWindow.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас неправильно прописан вызов функции.

Вместо

```
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(Ui_MainWindow.text_btn)
```

Пропишите

```
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.text_btn)
```

И самостоятельно настройте максимальную длину лейбла, сейчас она равна 10

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]